# How to read an Excel file using tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to know if there's an easy command to read and use data from an Excel file. I'm moving from `MATLAB` to `Python`, so I'd like to know if there's something simple as in `MATLAB`:

> data = xlsread(filename).

I need this to load data to train an ANN.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with Pandas

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

By convention, it's abbreviated as pd when imported:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Once imported, use Panda's [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) attribute to load the excel file as a Pandas Dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_excel('path/to/xlxs_file/') 
df.head()
```

Read more on Pandas [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_csv('./blahblah.csv',usecols = [0,1,2],skiprows = [0],header=None)
d = df.values
data = np.float32(d)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(150,5))
x = data
```

This is one of the ways to load a `.csv` file into TF.